# Routing is not working laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, laravel-routing

I have just installed fresh laravel 5.1, only root page is showing that

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    return view('welcome');
});
```

It's working perfectly but rather than any other route not working
like:

```
Route::get('user', function () {
   return "hello";
});
```

It throws exception 404 not found. Please help me to get out from this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your htaccess file also check weather mod_rewrite is enabled or not

Comment: Thanks chetan its working now  fine!

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of rewrite mode is not enabled in your system. Either you enable it or access through the following url with index.php

```
http://localhost/blog/public/index.php/user
```

Comment: Better to enable rewrite mode